# How can i disable row inside table in some conditionals using angular 7?

Tags: angular

So what i have is a table with rows, and what i need in some conditionals disable rows.

I've tried to use [disabled]='...' but it is said that 'Attribute [disabled] is not allowed here'

Comment: Table row does not have `disabled` attribute in W3C standards.

Comment: What do you mean by disabling ? Is there any action in your row ?

Comment: Yeap, i've an action which opens modal window when u click on row. I want to disable some rows, so user cant click on it.

Comment: Add your model <td> code here so we can edit it.

Comment: a table row can not be disabled nor should it. maybe a child button or an input, on which you can use [disabled] as you normally would

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `[disabled]` maybe you should try simple `*ngIf="condition"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to disable the particular row.

css:

```
.disabled {
 pointer-events: none;
}
```

Then apply that class in the row you want to disable. You can use ngClass in angular which will apply the class only if certain conditions met

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <span [ngClass]="{'disabled':item.value === 'item'}">{{item.value}}</span>
</div>
```

Above code will apply the class disabled if the item.value equals to item.